# Insert media file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

dear all
How to insert media file such as *.mepeg or *.mp3 ,..... files in SQL Server

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  2008 added FileStream, a hybrid between storing on the filesystem and the database.  Otherwise, you're looking to store binary data, generally called a BLOB in databases...

Answer (score 5):

- Should one store files in the database? [To BLOB or Not to BLOB](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64525/tr-2006-45.pdf):

> The study indicates that if objects
>   are larger than one megabyte on
>   average, NTFS has a clear advantage
>   over SQL Server. If the objects are
>   under 256 kilobytes, the database has
>   a clear advantage. Inside this range,
>   it depends on how write intensive the
>   workload is, and the storage age of a
>   typical replica in the system.

- How about filestream? [FILESTREAM Storage in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109%28SQL.100%29.aspx).

There are many more questions on this simple topic, when one starts to consider High Availability and Disaster Recoverability requirements, the need for a consistent backup-restore strategy, the question whether the media is accessed over an HTTP interface and the processing overhead of a URL that returns content from the database, and so on and so forth.

But to answer the naive question: you store media files in the database as `VARBINARY(MAX)` columns. You manipulate them in the client as [`SqlBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbinary.aspx) types. One must use streaming semantics when manipulating large BLOBs, like using [`CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx) as described in [Retrieving Large Data (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). If Win32 API access is needed, then FILESTREAM type must be used. More reading material on the topic, with samples, at [SQL Server Binary and Large-Value Data (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1904w6t.aspx).

Oh, and before I forget: you also need columns to store the file metadata, like its name and type. These are needed to add the `content-disposition` and `content-type` headers  if the media is streamed over HTTP responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE pubs
CREATE TABLE mycustomertable
(
user_login DEFAULT SUSER_SID, 
data_value
)

INSERT mycustomertable (data_value)
  VALUES (0x4F)
```

from http://en.allexperts.com/q/MS-SQL-1450/Binary-Data.htm

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with @JoshD, but if you **must** store binary files such as digital video/audio in the database, SQL Server provides [the `varbinary` datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx).

Note that the default maximum length for this type is 8000 bytes - likely not enough storage for the average audio/video file. Note the use of `varbinary(max)` for data larger than the 8K limit:

> max indicates that the maximum storage
>   size is 2^31-1 bytes.

Comment: If the database in question has a DBA (say, at your place of employment) then you'll _definitely_ want to consult with him/her on the use of varbinary and breaking out of the 8K limit.  It should be fine, but that's the kind of thing to run by the person in charge of that system.

Comment: @David Agreed! Again, I'm hardly recommending the above approach over storing large files elsewhere, but it's useful to understand that it exists. :)